# show route in newly launch google map app

Tags: google-maps

I'm looking for way to redirect user from our app to google map app to show route between two location. currently apple map is supporting route in united state only but i want to publish my app for other regions.

before few days apple launches google map app for ios, i want to redirect my user inside it.

right now i'm using following code to redirect user in apple maps :

```
    NSString * myLocString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"40.737893,-73.990173"];

    NSString * destString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"40.733893,-73.993173"];
NSString* queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"saddr=%@&daddr=%@",myLocString,destString];



NSString* searchQuery = nil;

searchQuery =  [queryString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?%@",searchQuery];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way to achieve this :

> BOOL openurlflag=[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:
>                     [NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]];
>
> if (openurlflag==0)// open apple maps {
>       NSString * myLocString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"40.737893,-73.990173"];
>
> ```
> NSString * destString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"40.733893,-73.993173"];
>
> NSString* queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"saddr=%@&daddr=%@",myLocString,destString];
>
> NSString* searchQuery = nil;
>
> searchQuery =  [queryString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>
> NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?%@",searchQuery];
>
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
>  } else if (openurlflag==1) // open google maps {
> NSString * myLocString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"40.737893,-73.990173"];
>
> NSString * destString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"40.733893,-73.993173"];
>
>         NSString* queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"saddr=%@&daddr=%@&directionsmode=transit",myLocString,destString];
>
>
> NSString* searchQuery = nil;
>
> searchQuery =  [queryString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
>
> NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?%@",searchQuery];
>
> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]]; }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

finally i got one link where you can do it by changing URLScheme.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/urlscheme